# Can I separate user and system trace files in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle 10g, the destinations for system and user generated trace files were controlled by the background_dump_dest and user_dump_dest Oracle parameters.

Starting in 11g these parameters are deprecated, and all trace files are written to the Diag Trace value in v$diag_info.

Is there any way to separate system and user trace files like you could in 10g?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can set the user and background dump destinations in 11g onward. One thing that might help is the TRACEFILE_IDENTIFIER parameter. I set this when I do a trace so that it is easy to find in the trace directory.

For example I setup a trace like this:

```
alter session set max_dump_file_size = unlimited;
ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = 'bobbydurrett';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10053 trace name context forever, level 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
```

My trace file has my name "bobbydurrett" in it so it is easy to search for it.

Bobby